# Removing line breaks NOT preceded by NULL

Tags: null, notepad++, newline

I've got a string of data that have random CRLF inserted in the lines which I need to remove and proper CRLF ending the data which I need to keep.

I've tried using Notepad++ regex trying to replace the following with empty:
[^NULL]\r\n

However, it does not remove the inserted CRLFs.  Any thoughts on how best to use this in Notepad++?

[Inserted CRLF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0fk9.png)

[Proper ending CRLF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOEUD.png)

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64773313/edit) and add sample input text and expected result in text format, **not image**.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace every linebreak that is not preceeded by "NULL".

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!NULL)\R`
- Replace with:    # a space OR any thing you want that will replace the linebreak
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!            # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't before:
    NULL            # literally NULL
)               # end lookbehind
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r or \n or \r\n)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: that worked perfectly ... thanks for the quick response and great explanation.

Comment: @ShaunBadertscher: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but you can use the `Extended` search mode to match `\r\n` specifically.

Find what: `NULL\r\n`
Replace with:

[image: Replace dialog box]

Before:
[image: Before replacement]

After:
[image: After replacement]